# Bootstrap modal close causes parent page to expand to 100% of screen in IE9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am utilizing the bootstrap modal with an iFrame.  If I click outside the modal or use the Esc key, the parent page is fine.  However, If I programmatically close the modal, the parent content is forced to 100% of the screens width.

The other interesting part is that the navbar is forced into "collapse" mode - the actual navbar is hidden and the collapsed version is show, almost as if bootstrap is trying to render the true mobile version.

There is nothing special about the page, just a typical container with rows set to to col-lg-12, so there must be something with the implementation.

JS to call modal:

```
$("#ModalTemplate .modal-body").html('<iframe width="' + 
    width + '" height="' + height + 
    '" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="' + 
    src + '"></iframe>'
);
```

JS to close modal:

```
window.parent.'$'('#ModalTemplate').modal('hide');
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue before?  What other information can I provide?